# Run time error '1004' Application defined or object defined error on Vlookup function

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, userform

I am trying to utilize `Vlookup` function, according to the `Textbox1` value user put in in `Userform Guntest`, automatically looking for corresponding features of the gun.
However the program currently doesn't run as it reminds me

> 'Runtime error '1004', method 'Range of object' _Global' failed.

The error appears on `Retrieve1=…`

I will be appreciated if you could help me to check where the problem is as I have really limited knowledge and experience on using VBA.

Thanks in advance.

It looks like some objects is undefined but I can't figure out where.

The module 1 code is:

```
Public Guncode As String
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Call Vlookup

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Vlookup()

    Dim Retrieve1 As String
    Dim Retrieve2 As String
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim FinalColumn As Long
    Dim WholeRange As String

    If GunTest.TextBox1 = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    If GunTest.TextBox1 <> "" Then

        MsgBox Guncode
    End If
    End If

    With Sheets(1)

        FinalRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        FinalColumn = Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
        WholeRange = "A2:" & CStr(FinalColumn) & CStr(FinalRow)

        Retrieve1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Trim(Guncode), Range(WholeRange), 1, False) 'Locate specific tool according to QR code number
        Retrieve2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Trim(Guncode), Range(WholeRange), 5, False) 'Locate specific gun type according to QR code number

        If Guncode = "" Then
            MsgBox "This gun doesn't exist in database!"
        Else
            MsgBox "The tool number is:" & Retrieve1 & vbCrLf & "The gun type is:" & Retrieve2
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

---

The userform code is:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If TextBox1 = "" Then Exit Sub 'Set condition 1 of exiting the program

    Guncode = GunTest.TextBox1

    With Me

        Call Module1.Test

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub PartID_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

It should run properly but it doesn't.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Within your `With` statement, you need to have your ranges like so `FinalRow = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row`.  You need to add "." before your referenced ranges or cells

Comment: @ACohen Thanks. I added "." just now but seems like the error is still there

Comment: Can you please update your code in your question as well.. And make sure that you added the `.` to all of your ranges in your code.

Comment: @ACohen Was trying to but I didn't find the edit button of the post? Sorry I am pretty new on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you were passing in a number as the column letter value. CSTR() doesnt magically transform it into the letter equivalent but I like your enthusiasm.

Second, your method will bomb if the value isnt found - so you'll need to write your own error handling for it.

```
Sub Vlookup()
    Dim Retrieve1 As String
    Dim Retrieve2 As String
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim FinalColumn As Long
    Dim WholeRange As String
    Dim vArr
    Dim col_Letter As String

    If GunTest.TextBox1 = "" Then
        Exit Sub
        If GunTest.TextBox1 <> "" Then
            MsgBox Guncode
        End If
    End If

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        FinalRow = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        FinalColumn = .Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
        vArr = Split(Cells(1, FinalColumn).Address(True, False), "$")
        col_Letter = vArr(0)
        WholeRange = "A2:" & col_Letter & CStr(FinalRow) '<---- you were passing a number in as the column value
        Retrieve1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Trim(Guncode), .Range(WholeRange), 1, False) 'Locate specific tool according to QR code number
        Retrieve2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Trim(Guncode), .Range(WholeRange), 5, False) 'Locate specific gun type according to QR code number

        If Guncode = "" Then
            MsgBox "This gun doesn't exist in database!"
        Else
            MsgBox "The tool number is:" & Retrieve1 & vbCrLf & "The gun type is:" & Retrieve2
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

***1. I am not sure what is the reason using Address(True, False) for row number.***

This comes from a combination of these two functions. The true/false setting is telling the funciton to use/not use absolute references in the address.

Split ( expression [,delimiter] [,limit] [,compare] )
    https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php

expression.Address (RowAbsolute, ColumnAbsolute, ReferenceStyle, External, RelativeTo)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address

***Shouldn't Cell (1, FinalColumn) stands for the column number?***

No, the cells fucntiosn basically returns an intersection/address of rows & column.

Try this for example: debug.Print; thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,2)

***You mentioned CSTR doesn't magically transform to letter equivalent so what would it transform to? Could you further elaborate?***

This is a data type conversion function. CSTR(666) essentially does this: this 666 becomes this  "666"

***2. vArr(0). I am confused with what does the parameter 0 stands for in the bracket. Actually this is a general question I always have regarding to parameter specification.***

This is an array position refence. The split function returns an array of strings. Since we're using to capture the column label value, we only need to reference the first position.

***(3) I tried copy your code and run it but still reminds me error on the same row.***

Works fine for me unless there is no returning value, which returns an error which is what I meant by "bomb."

Comment: Thanks for your answer first. However there is still somewhere confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer first. However there is still somewhere confusing. 1. I am not sure what is the reason using Address(True, False) for row number. Shouldn't Cell (1, FinalColumn) stands for the column number? You mentioned CSTR doesn't magically transform to letter equivalent so what would it transform to? Could you further elaborate? 2. vArr(0). I am confused with what does the parameter 0 stands for in the bracket. Actually this is a general question I always have regarding to parameter specification. (3) I tried copy your code and run it but still reminds me error on the same row.

Comment: I also don't understand what do you mean by "the method will bomb". It doesn't seem like there is a loop in my program. @Doug Coats

Comment: I copied your codes again and ran it, now it reminds "unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class". Shall I delete "worksheetfunction" in the code? @Doug Coats

Comment: @anctorHu no thats the error message you get when you dont find a value. I did tell you you'd have to account for this with custom error handling